# EmailSender Exception reading response

Tags: java, spring-boot

I believe I have followed the guidelines correctly from this website https://vandeneyndefilip.nu/spring-boot/spring-boot-sending-email/, but I get an exception reading response.

I tried to find a solution to the problem on the internet and all I could get was to change the port from 465 to 587. unfortunately, I did use port 587 from the start

1. this is my application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=myemail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=mypassword
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

2. this is my implementation

```
            String jsonData = user.toJson();

            System.out.println(jsonData);
            byte[] arrayBlob = blobTemplate.getBytes(1, (int) blobTemplate.length());
            String data = new String(arrayBlob);

            String newData = MustacheProcessor.mustacheProcess(data, jsonData);

            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            message.setTo(user.getEmail());
            message.setSubject(template.getSubject());
            message.setText(newData);

            emailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried to see the data transfer on this line, and everything was fine

```
            message.setTo(user.getEmail());
            message.setSubject(template.getSubject());
            message.setText(newData);
```

I have read the trace and there seems to be a problem when sending email

`emailSender.send(message);`

3. this is a half of the trace

```
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2460)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2187)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:517)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:436)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:322)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:311)
    at com.sender.tugaskp2.tugaskp2.service.impl.EmailServiceImp.sendSinglePayslip(EmailServiceImp.java:55)
    at com.sender.tugaskp2.tugaskp2.controller.EmailController.sendSinglePayslip(EmailController.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by replacing the network that I use and activating less secure app access for my email. I'm not sure this is the most appropriate answer to this problem.

I got the answer from this link
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-send-email-via-smtp/

have a nice day